# How to prove this relation between Ramsey Numbers: $R(s, t) ≤ R(s, t-1) + R(s-1, t)$ for $s,t>2$

Tags: inequality, graph-theory, ramsey-theory

I am trying to prove that

$$R(s, t) ≤ R(s, t-1) + R(s-1, t) $$
for $s,t>2$, where $R(s,t)$ is the Ramsey number of $(s,t)$, and I'd be really grateful for a hint that gets me started.

Comment: Hint: pick a vertex $v$ in the graph, and split the other vertices in the graph into two sets: those connected to $v$ by red edges and those connected to $v$ by blue edges.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usual approach is very nice: Suppose you are given the complete graph on $n=R(s,t-1)+R(s-1,t)$ vertices, and a coloring of its edges with colors red and blue.

Pick one of the vertices, call it $v$. Divide the remaining $n-1$ into two sets $A$ and $B$, according to whether they are joined to $v$ by a red or a blue edge, respectively. Let $a=|A|$ and $b=|B|$. Then $a+b=n-1$, so either $a\ge R(s,t-1)$ or $b\ge R(s-1,t)$. This is because otherwise, $a+b\le n-2$.

It should be easy to see how to continue from here.

---

Just for fun, let's compute some upper bounds using this inequality, knowing that $R(2,t)=R(t,2)=t$.

We have $R(3,3)\le R(2,3)+R(3,2)=3+3=6$. In fact, we have equality in this case. Moreover, the usual "party argument" one sees sometimes showing $R(3,3)\le 6$ is precisely the argument above.

$R(4,3)\le R(3,3)+R(4,2)=6+4=10$. In fact, one can extend the argument above a bit to show that if *both* $R(s,t-1)$ and $R(s-1,t)$ are even, then we have [strict inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1927889/462). This means that $R(4,3)\le 9$, and again this is sharp.

$R(4,4)\le R(3,4)+R(4,3)=18$. Again, equality holds.

$R(5,3)\le R(5,2)+R(4,3)=5+9=14$ and, again, equality holds.

$R(5,4)\le R(5,3)+R(4,4)=14+18=32$. (So $R(5,4)\le31$ as both $14$ and $18$ are even.) In fact, $R(5,4)=24$, and the bound ceases being optimal around here.

Improving this bound turns out to be remarkably difficult and the subject of much work.

For a nice up to date list of the known values and bounds for Ramsey numbers, together with references, see the [dynamic survey](http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/DS1) on "Small Ramsey numbers" by Stanisław Radziszowski, last updated March 3, 2017, in the Electronic Journal of Combinatorics. (I see I had suggested the same paper as an answer to this other [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14020/known-bounds-and-values-for-ramsey-numbers/).)