# How to prove this relation between Ramsey Numbers: $R(s,t)≤R(s,t−1)+R(s−1,t)-1$ for $s,t>2$ when $R(s,t-1)$ and $R(s-1,t)$ are even.

Tags: combinatorics, inequality, ramsey-theory

I am beginner in combinatorics and have been following this book **PRINCIPLE AND TECHNIQUES IN COMBINATORICS** by CHEN CHUAN-CHONG.
In this book the authors improves the relation $R(s,t)≤R(s,t−1)+R(s−1,t)$ for $s,t>2$ to above relation by making a constraint that $R(s,t-1)$ and $R(s-1,t)$ are both even.

I am unable to follow through the author's reasoning for this proof.

Please help.

Comment: You argue that there is no graph with an odd number of vertices and such that all of the vertices are of odd degree. The reason is that adding the degrees of all vertices gives you twice the number of edges of the graph.

Comment: See also: [Strengthening of a lemma in Ramsey Theory: $R(m, n) \le R(m-1, n) + R(m, n-1)-1$ if both numbers are even](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1927889)