# Ramsey numbers Olympiad combo

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math, ramsey-theory

Show that if l,s are positive integers, then
$r(l,s) \leq {l + s - 2 \choose l - 1} $

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Combinatorics/Bounds_for_Ramsey_numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to prove this claim, I will use the result $r(l, s) \leq r(l - 1, s) + r(l, s - 1)$. A proof of this inequality is shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/101837/how-to-prove-this-relation-between-ramsey-numbers-rs-t-%E2%89%A4-rs-t-1-rs-1).

When $l = s = 2$, we have $r(2, 2) = 2$, and the claim holds. Now if the relation holds for $r(l - 1, s)$ and $r(l, s - 1)$, then one has

$$r(l, s) \leq r(l - 1, s) + r(l, s - 1) = {l + s - 2\choose l -1}, $$

where the last equality follows from using the induction hypothesis with Pascal's Identity. By induction, the conclusion follows.