# Best known bounds for Ramsey numbers

Tags: reference-request, ramsey-theory

I realize a [similar](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14020/known-bounds-and-values-for-ramsey-numbers) question has been asked before but what I want to know is a little different and is not answered by the link in the answer to that question. I am interested in knowing the best known general upper and lower bounds (non-asymptotic) for an arbitrary [Ramsey number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey%27s_theorem#Ramsey_numbers) $R(k,l)$. Similarly the best known general upper and lower bounds for an arbitrary diagonal Ramsey number $R(k,k)$. It would be good if someone could also tell me asymptotic bounds in these cases as well.(I am not sure whether wikipedia is upto date.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at [this](http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/ds1/sur/pdf) paper by  Radziszowski. [This](http://ginger.indstate.edu/ge/RAMSEY/index.html) site is also up to date with new results about $R(k,l)$.

Comment: It is worth noting that although the title of the paper is "Small Ramsey Numbers", it does have an extensive survey of *general* bounds, and has plenty of additional references.