# Directory for known bound of Ramsey numbers?

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, ramsey-theory

I must admit I'm not a google connoisseur, but I have not been able to find a place where I can find known lower bounds for many Ramsey numbers, something ideal would be if I could insert (3,44) and receive the two best known bounds to the problem. Where can I find this? Does it exist?

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/14021/462) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/170663/462).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dynamic survey "[Small Ramsey Numbers](http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/DS1/pdf)", maintained by Stanisław P. Radziszowski, is an essential reference.

You ask in the comments about $R(3,45)$. The paper contains a table of lower bounds for $R(3,k)$ with $k \leq 38$, suggesting $R(3,45)$ has not been investigated explicitly. You will have to instead look at more general results for $R(3,k)$. For example, I find on page 8 (item c)
$$R(3,4k+1)≥6R(3,k+1)−5.$$

For your example, this means $$R(3,45)≥6R(3,12)−5≥6⋅52−5=307.$$

Page 9 (item 3) states
$$
R(3,k) \leq \frac{k^2}{\log k},
$$
which gives
$$
R(3,45) \leq 531.
$$

Taken together, we have
$$
307 \leq R(3,45) \leq 531.
$$

Comment: Thanks, I read this, but isn't there a website which is just a big table, I want known bounds for $R(3,45)$ Where can I find this?

Comment: @Bananarama given the lack of google results for such a table I guess it probably doesn't exist and your best bet is the paper mentioned. Item (3) on page 9 then seems to be the best known bound for $R(3,45)$ based on a quick look.