# What is Ramsey Theory ? what is its own importance in maths?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, ramsey-theory

3 days ago , i had a discussion with a close friend who studies physics - still a student - . 
and i was telling her about the biggest known numbers in maths , so i told her about numbers such googol and googolplex, then about Graham number and she asked me , what is the application of this number in maths problems ? i answered , it's a solution  of a famous problem in Ramsey theory and Ramsey theory is a branch if modern mathematics .

but suddenly , the question arise ! what is Ramsey theory ? what is its importance ? has it any relation with other branches like mathematical logic or group theory ?

is it advanced topic in maths ?

so i have googled and found that it's a branch which talk about the properties of particular structures in maths when we divide this structure into new substructures .

this is all what i could understand !

so can  give us more information , reference for beginners , application of it in other branches in science like physics or chemistry , the relation with other mathematical branches and resources for more readings ?

Comment: Do you see the questions under the heading, "Related", on this page? A lot of them are about Ramsey Theory, and you might find some of them interesting and helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ramsey theory has had a major impact in Banach space theory. Its first application, it seems, was in the proof of the justly famous Rosenthal $\ell_1$-theorem. Relatively recently, it was used by Gowers in his dichotomy result.

[This book](http://books.google.com/books?id=LSO8lqXQslYC&pg=PA124&lpg=PA124&dq=application+banach+ramsey+theory&source=bl&ots=g7IYpPWyVD&sig=3rryDKc4IUi3K3R3FhwOoDslPe8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=fyG3UZvDG5HU8wT424GIDg&ved=0CD4Q6AEwBDgK#v=onepage&q=application%20banach%20ramsey%20theory&f=false) seems to contain the major recent results.

Joeseph Diestel's text
*Sequences and Series in Banach Spaces* contains a nice treatment of some basic results from Ramsey Theorey and several of the applications thereof, including a proof of the Rosenthal $\ell_1$ theorem, to the geometry of Banach spaces.

[This article](http://users.uoa.gr/~pdodos/Publications/26-DLT-Problems.pdf) contains many open problems of a Ramsey flavor.

Some other surveys:

1) Ramsey Methods in Banach Spaces, W.T Gowers, contained in chapter 24 of *Handbook of the Geometry of Banach Spaces, Vol 2*.

2) *Applications of Ramsey Theorems to Banach Space Theorey*, Edward Odell, 1981, Austin: University of Texas Press.

Of course, none of this is easy. Gowers won the field medal for his dichotomy result.  The following quote from his [biography](http://www-history.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/Biographies/Gowers.html) seems relevant:

"William Timothy Gowers has provided important contributions to functional analysis, making extensive use of methods from combination theory. These two fields apparently have little to do with each other, and a significant achievement of Gowers has been to combine these fruitfully."

Comment: what about reference to only Ramsey Theory for beginners not for its applications ?

Comment: @MathsLover A bit of Googling produced [this](http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/~gouldm/ramsey.pdf). Also, [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/271839/good-way-to-learn-ramsey-theory?rq=1) contains suggestions for introductory material.

Comment: David Mitra , thanx :))

Answer (score 3):

Funny that you should mention mathematical logic. Frank Plumpton Ramsey introduced (what came to be known as) Ramsey's theorem in a 1928 paper title "On a Problem of Formal Logic". Ramsey applied his theorem to solve a certain decision problem in predicate logic. If I remember right, he used it to show that the problem, whether a given first-order sentence **of a certain kind** has an infinite model, is effectively decidable.

Edited to add the modifier "of a certain kind" because it sure won't work for arbitrary first order sentences. I seem to recall now that Ramsey's decision procedure applies to universal (or existential-universal) first-order sentences in a purely relational language, i.e., no operation symbols. Or something like that.